# BindingFlags for abstract class?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find the right BindingFlags to use when using `GetMethod` from an abstract class.

```
public abstract class A
{
    private void ConsoleOutput(string text)
    {
    }
}
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
this.GetType().GetMethod("ConsoleOutput", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
```

Even though the *class* is abstract, the *method* is still instance.

Answer (score 0):

Private methods can only be found on their corresponding type, not an a derived type. So make sure the `Type` object you're calling `GetMethod` on is referring to your class `A`. The BindingFlags Jashaszun posted are correct.

```
typeof(A).GetMethod("ConsoleOutput", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```